# Linear operators and the inner product

Tags: operators, hilbert-space, vectors, notation

I pick the inner product involving the linear operator $\Omega$, $\langle i|\Omega|j\rangle$, from the $n\times n$ matrix $\Omega_{ij}$ as structured in [page 21](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.fisica.net/mecanica-quantica/Shankar%2520-%2520Principles%2520of%2520quantum%2520mechanics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi3vpaasYnbAhWCro8KHRnTDisQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw3t59bGXXAPQE5joxcE1CKZ) of *Principles of Quantum Mechanics* by R. Shankar. Is it true that $\langle i|(\Omega|j\rangle)=\langle i|\Omega j\rangle = (\langle i|\Omega)|j\rangle$?

There is a reason behind me asking this. Let me take you back to page 21 again. At the very bottom of the page are printed a few lines:

> A mnemonic: the elements of the first column are simply the components of the first transformed basis vector $|1'\rangle = \Omega |1\rangle $ in the given basis.

This is fine. Now, I wish to convince myself that the same matrix $\Omega_{ij} $ acts to the left of the row vector $\langle V|$ to give $\langle V|\Omega$ in the basis $(\langle 1|, \langle 2|,....,\langle n|) $. Let me do that here.

I have $\langle V| = \begin{bmatrix}
 {v_1}^* . .  {v_n}^*
\end{bmatrix}$. To compute the component of $\langle V|\Omega$ along $\langle 1|$—say, I do the following(correct me if I am wrong), $$(\langle V|\Omega) | 1\rangle \langle 1| = {{v_1}^*}' \langle 1|= (\sum_{j} {v_j}^* \langle j|\Omega|1\rangle) \langle 1|$$

Where $\langle V|\Omega = \sum_{j}  {v_j}^* \langle j|\Omega$. In general, to compute a component along $\langle i|$ I do, $$(\langle V|\Omega) | i\rangle \langle i| ={{v_i}^*}' \langle i| = (\sum_{j} {v_j}^* \langle j|\Omega|i\rangle) \langle i|$$

I can obtain all components by doing the following, $$\begin{bmatrix}
 {{v_1}^*}' . .  {{v_n}^*}'
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
 {v_1}^* .  . {v_n}^*
\end{bmatrix} \Omega_{ji}$$

I arrive at the same matrix($\Omega_{ij} = \Omega_{ji} $ in this case) and I am convinced. Well, not so much. Here the first column of $\Omega_{ij}$, according to what I did above, gives the component of $\langle j|\Omega$ along $\langle 1|$. The mnemonic suggests otherwise. I stand to reason that $\langle i|(\Omega|j\rangle)=\langle i|\Omega j\rangle = (\langle i|\Omega)|j\rangle$.

Comment: Isn't what you are saying true just because matrix multiplication is associative?

Comment: @AaronStevens how could I oblivious to that?! My goodness! I appreciate this!

Comment: Exactly, it's just because of assocciativity, but provided that you keep the order the same.